# how does Git deal with misspelled commands?

Tags: git

I said

```
git rebase --abor
```

and, rather than complaining, Git aborted the rebase as if I had said `--abort`. What's going on here? Clearly Git has some internal algorithm for cutting me some slack; what is it?

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/parse-options.c#L326 ? `what is it?` I mean, what is to explain here? If there's a part of an option and only one option matches from beginning of the string, it is used.

Comment: @KamilCuk Cool! How good does the match have to be? I've seen people claim that `set-upsteam` (omitted 'r') works without complaint. So do we just keep matching forward until end-or-mismatch?

Comment: Many commands accept any correctly spelled, unambiguous prefix of the full option string. Think of it as abbreviation rather than spelling correction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Option* names can be specified with a unique prefix. No other option to `rebase` starts with `--abor`, so it can be unambiguously treated as `--abort`. (This is a property of the GNU `getopt` library, not specific to Git.)

This does not work with other misspellings, like `--abotr`, and it does not apply to subcommands at all. `git rebas` is an error, not an abbreviation for `git rebase`.

Comment: "This is a property of the GNU getopt library, not specific to Git" Whoa! You learn something new every day.

Comment: @matt: yes, although Git has its own copy of the getopt functionality, extended for Git's purposes - they've just kept this particular property working.